# How to fetch joomla article custom fields in another component?

Tags: articles, custom-field, joomla-3.7

I have created some custom fields in my joomla article from backend now I want to fetch them in another component. What would be the code to achieve it?

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to retrieve Articles by FieldValues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to fetch custom field values by article id

```
<?php       
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php'); //load fields helper
$customFieldnames = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article_id, true); // get custom field names by article id
$customFieldIds = array_map(create_function('$o', 'return $o->id;'), $customFieldnames); //get custom field Ids by custom field names
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', array('ignore_request' => true)); //load fields model
$customFieldValues = $model->getFieldValues($customFieldIds , $item->content_item_id); //Fetch values for custom field Ids
?>
```

---

**EDIT:**

According to [php.net](https://www.php.net/create_function)

> `create_function` function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 8.0.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

A modern replacement is simply to create a flat, indexed array of `id` property values using `array_column()`:

```
$customFieldIds = array_column($customFieldnames, 'id');
```

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to retrieve Articles by FieldValues?

Comment: But you have not defined $article_id (and a spelling mistake).  How do you find the article ID?

Comment: Ok here is how you get the active article ID
`
$app       = JFactory::getApplication(); // Access the Application Object
$menu      = $app->getMenu(); // Load the JMenuSite Object
$active    = $menu->getActive(); // Load the Active Menu Item as an stdClass Object
$article_id = $active->id;`

Comment: create_function is depreciated in PHP 7.2.  What would be the best way to fetch without it?

Answer (score 4):

#### This function will allow display of JCFields anywhere in any extension desired, including templates.

The first parameter is the only requirement and will dump the JCF data, based on the item ID inserted. The default context is **com_content.article** and that can be set to any context where JCF data is held.

The second param is the **field ID**. If set, the data for that single custom field will be retrieved.

The third param will allow calls to specific JCF database fields. This is ideal for minimal data retrieval. It is triggered only when a single **$srcId** value is detected. I considered using a boolean method to allow choosing when needed, but I didn't need it for the project. It can be modified as desired.

The last param will set the context value such as **com_users.users**

```
function getJCFields($srcId, $fieldId=null, $dbfields=null, $context=null)
{
    if( is_null($context) )
        $context = 'com_content.article';
    
    if( is_array($srcId) || is_object($srcId) ) {
        JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
        $jfields = FieldsHelper::getFields($context, $srcId, true);
    }
    else
    if( is_int($srcId) ) 
    {
        if( is_null($dbfields) )
            $dbfields = 'id,label,value,item_id';
        
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $db->setQuery('
        SELECT '.$dbfields.'
        FROM #__fields 
        LEFT JOIN #__fields_values ON #__fields.id = #__fields_values.field_id
        WHERE context = "'.$context.'" 
        AND #__fields_values.item_id = '.$srcId.'
        AND #__fields.state = 1
        ');
        
        $jfields = $db->loadObjectList();
    }
    
    $fieldval=[];
    foreach($jfields as $val)
    {
        $fieldval[$val->id] = (object)['label'=>$val->label,'value'=>$val->value];
    }
    
    $fval = $fieldval;
    if( !is_null($fieldId) ) {
        $fval = $fieldval[$fieldId];
    }

    return $fval;
}
```

#### Usage Methods

Set a variable with the source item and category ID as an associative array

```
$srcid = ['id'=>24, 'catid'=>5];
```

Get field label

```
getJCFields($srcid, 9)->label;
```

Get field value

```
getJCFields($srcid, 9)->value;
```

*Note: each output instance should be cased in a **!empty()** condition*

Of course the conditional check can be written into the function for better completeness in the process.

#### Get creative with an array of fields

```
$fields = [2,3,4,5,6,8];

$cell=[];
foreach($fields as $fid) 
{
    $lbl = getJCFields($srcid, $fid)->label;
    $val = getJCFields($srcid, $fid)->value;
    if( !empty($val) ) {
        $cell[] = '<div class="tr"><div class="cell lbl">'.$lbl.'</div><div class="cell val">'.$val.'</div></div>';
    }
}

$fieldtbl = '
<div class="tbl chart">
    '.implode('', $cell).'
</div>
';
```

#### Other use

If you just want to get the JCF array for an item, then use within your special function, just use only the **item ID** for a minimal DB query for specific rows.

*Note the **ID must be an integer** so it must **not** be enclosed in quotes*

From **com_content**

```
getJCFields(293);
```

From **com_users**

*Note: the $dbfields param can use aliases*

```
getJCFields(16, null, 'id,value,label,item_id AS uid', 'com_users.user');
```

**Output array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [label] => Address
            [value] => 400 W Church St #200, Orlando, FL 32801
            [item_id] => 293
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [label] => Phone
            [value] => 407-440-7900
            [item_id] => 293
        )

)
```

#### end

---

***Update:*** Alternative to get data from elements not included in the default return object which output only *label* and *value*.

```
getJCFields($srcid)[9]->author_name;
getJCFields($srcid)[9]->params;
getJCFields($srcid)[9]->description;
```

---

Comment: A code review for you (and researchers) to consider: https://3v4l.org/S3NaQ . If you like any parts of it, I welcome you to edit them into your answer.  If you would like me to explain anything further, just ask.  I noticed that `item_id` was not used in `$fieldval[$val->id] = (object)['label'=>$val->label,'value'=>$val->value];` despite being declared in the fallback SELECT values of the query.

Comment: @mickmackusa I didn't need that item_id index for the project, solely because it only called for the label and value. As stated in the post, anyone can add or remove what ever is desired to serve their purpose. It is merely base to build on.